# Placing a div inside another div on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery

With a button click I am able to generate draggable divs that are then placed inside another div(container). The divs that are created from the button click are automatically placed on the left side of the parent(container) div. Then the user has the ability to drag it to the desired location. Is there a way to let the user generate the new div and then let them determine the location of this new div with a mouse click?  [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/13/)

As the user is figuring out the location and hovering through the container provide some sort of temporary guide something like this below:

[image]

Jquery

```
$('#button').click(function (e) {
    $('<div />', {
        'class': 'draggable ui-widget-content',
        text: $('textarea').val(),
        appendTo: '.middle-side',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent'
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Enter Text Here!"></textarea>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Add Div with Text" />
<br/>
<div>
    <div class="middle-side"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I am not misunderstanding the question, why not just making the position of the div (inner) absolute and set its coordinates onclick of the parent div? it would be pretty much setting the inner div's coordinates to be X == [currentMouseX - (divWidth/2), currentMouseY - (divHeight/2)]

Comment: Not sure I am following. Could show that in Jsfiddle?

Comment: I just posted it, both examples. I think the first one is more directly related, after re-reading your question, but you could check both of them. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was talking about:

Two options:

On mouseover move the div:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lqebpaov/

```
document.getElementById('parentDiv').addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    var child = document.getElementById('childDiv');
    var mouseX = event.clientX || event.pageX;
    var mouseY = event.clientY || event.pageY;
    var top = mouseY - 50;
    var left = mouseX - 50;
    child.style.top = top.toString()+"px";
    child.style.left = left.toString()+"px";
});
```

On click display the div:
http://jsfiddle.net/7s2mykr9/

```
document.getElementById('parentDiv').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var child = document.getElementById('childDiv');
    var mouseX = event.clientX || event.pageX;
    var mouseY = event.clientY || event.pageY;
    var top = mouseY - 50;
    var left = mouseX - 50;
    child.style.top = top.toString()+"px";
    child.style.left = left.toString()+"px";
    child.style.visibility = "visible";
});
```

the code is there, just clean up the math.

I hope it helps

Comment: Ok nice, I would need a combination of the two!

Answer (score 0):

This example will create a div when your mouse enters the div. When you click on the new div you can move it around and when you release the mouse click the div will stay where you left it. You can then pick it up and move it around as many times as you want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>example</title>
<style>
    #testArea{
        display:block;
        height:200px;
        width:200px;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
    #testArea div{
        position:relative;
        display:block;
        background:green;
        height:20px;
        width:100px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mousePosition"></div>
    <div id="dragState">Drag state false</div>
    <div id="testArea"></div>

<script>
    var dragging=false;
    document.getElementById("testArea").addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
        if(!this.firstElementChild&&!this.firstChild){
            var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
            newDiv.innerHTML="Hello World";
            newDiv.addEventListener("mousedown",function(e){
                this.style.background="red";
                dragging=true;
                document.getElementById("dragState").innerHTML="Drag state true";
            },false);
            document.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
                document.getElementById("mousePosition").innerHTML="X: "+e.clientX+" Y: "+e.clientY;
                if(dragging){
                    var rect = document.getElementById("testArea").getBoundingClientRect();
                    newDiv.style.top = e.clientY-rect.top+"px";
                    newDiv.style.left = e.clientX-rect.left+"px";
                }
            },false);
            document.addEventListener("mouseup",function(e){
                newDiv.style.background="green";
                dragging=false;
                document.getElementById("dragState").innerHTML="Drag state false";
            },false);

            this.appendChild(newDiv);
        }

    },false);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
$('.middle-side').on('click',function (e) {
var x = (e.pageX -this.offsetLeft)+'px', y=(e.pageY -this.offsetTop) +'px';
$('<div />', {
    'class': 'draggable ui-widget-content',
    text: $('textarea').val(),
    appendTo: '.middle-side',
    draggable: {
        containment: 'parent'
    }
}).css({
    "position" : "absolute",
    "top" : y,
    "left" : x
});
});
```

I added this to the css:

```
.middle-side {position:relative;}
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/16/)

Comment: Oh yes this getting closer. But the desired order is: first append the text to the div with the button click and then place the location through the mouse click. Should only allow click for a position inside `<div class="middle-side"></div>` and no where else.

Comment: Umm.. yeah. It does that....  Maybe I pasted the wrong link....  http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/16/

Comment: Add `overflow:hidden;` to `.middle-side` class if you don't want the created divs to appear to be outside.